In Laravel Horizon, how do you get data to show up in the "Data" section?
In Laravel Horizon, if you select a job, there is a section on that page labelled "Data". Mine is blank, but I would love to put some data there, so I know what's going on. I have a class that implements "ShouldQueue". Where do I put my data in this class so that it shows up in the "Data" section?
Thanks.

Any data passed into the constructor of the job's class will appear in the data section. for instance if your constructor looks like this:
protected $someData;
protected $someVar;

public function __construct(Collection $someCollection, string $someString){

$this->someData = $someCollection;
$this->someVar = $someString;

}

This will then show in the data panel as:
{
    "someData": [],
    "someVar": ""
}

You cannot add data to the data panel after the job has been created (unless you want to heavily modify Horizon).
